# Preparing dataset with MultiLabels for classification in caffe

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I am trying to build multilabel classifier so I would be able to identify and  count objects in the picture. I have my own dataset that I have collected, and I labeled regions.

For the sake of simplicity, this is an example. Let's say that I am building a classifier to classify dogs and cats that appear in the same image, I have prepared the dataset in a way that I define regions.

if the image's size is 1200*1200

- First region: [[0,600],[0,1200] will be labeled as a 0 (cat),
- Second region: [[600,1200],[0,1200] will be labeled as a 1 (dog).

[image: Example]

By reading this example in [here](http://www.kostyaev.me/article/Multilabel%20Dataset/), I couldn't figure out how to define regions so I train the classifier to know that an object X is in region [x,y,w,z] ?
Preparing the script this way would help me to categorize the image, but it wouldn't help counting number of objects in the image

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you are mixing two tasks: classification and detection. Please read [faster RCNN](https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn) the implementation there takes advantage of labeling similar to what you have to detect and label the detected regions.

Comment: Thanks! It's not trivial on how to train costume dataset in FRCNN. I have defined regions as I mentioned, what is the best case to tell the system to consider A in region [x,y,z,w]  or should I modify the code to do that ?

Comment: I think the easiest approach would be to mimic VOC notation (using XML file per image) and then train FRCNN on the modified annotations.

Comment: I have done that, but I had some troubles training the model. Can you point to any tutorial or practical instructions ?